Can someone explain how to adjust opamp CA3140 offset null with "single supply"?

I found some circuit with offset null adjustment but it work with Single supply. Can someone explain it please?

Da Khoa - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

Fig 26 Shows an exmple in the datasheet for a precision rectifier with a single supply as you have shown.
There are 2 Other ways to improve te resoluton with fixed R's also on an earlier page bottom.
With the same input voltage as pin 3, you may adjust for 0 mV out if the loop gain is not too high, but it cannot be done open loop.
